# Comparing 10m records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have requirement to compare 10 million accounts by (SSN) or (LName & Address) and find out accounts belongs to same person (SSN) or person in family (Name & Address). There can be multiple joint account holders on same account. So query should be recursive to get accounts matching with each account holder + resulting accounts should apply same logic further.

Sample table

```
AccountNo   |   Account Holders|        SSN 
12345678    |   Father         |    3333333333
12345678    |   Mother         |    4444444444

23232323    |   Son            |    5555555555

45454545    |   Father         |    3333333333
45454545    |   Son            |    5555555555
45454545    |   Daughter       |    1111111111

98989898    |   wife           |    1010101010
98989898    |   Son            |    5555555555
```

There will be other columns for Name and address. The address comparison logic is tricky hence I have used function to compare two addresses.

Initially I used cursor to process comparison logic and get all matching accounts under same group. However it takes too much time and expected to run for few days to process all 10 millions records.

I am trying to find another solution which will be faster. My first approach is to get all accounts with SSN match and create group then I will try for Name & Address.

I am trying to use CTE to get groups. So for above example I want all above accounts under same groupid. And there will be other families with separate groupid.

1st thing, I have collected all groups having same SSN. Now I want to merge all those accounts held by multiple SSN and now falls under separate groups.

This is initial CTE I have used to get groups by SSN

```
;WITH CTE_SGroup AS
(
    SELECT 
        AccountNo, SSN,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SSN) SGROUPID
    FROM 
        AcctTable
)
```

Now, I am not able get query to merge all these accounts recursively.

Any help on this issue will be helpful.

Additional:
Here is sample example. I have this table and third column is expected column.

```
Acct#   SSNGrp      Expected Result
1       4           1
1       5           1
2       6           1
4       2           1
4       4           1
4       6           1
3       7           2
5       7           2
```

Starting processing with account 1, first two rows will have same group. Now for all SSNGrp 4 and 5 from second column will result in same group. However SSNgrp 4 also falls under Acct# 4 hence all 3 rows for Acct# 4 are assigned to same group. recursively, because of SSNgrp 6, Accnt 2 will also be in group 1.

Comment: Any concrete question? You can find some examples by googling - CTE, recursion, SqlServer..

Comment: I have seen few examples. But for this scenario I am unable to find one. If we take the given example, I am basically trying to assign family id for each family. So it is like a multi level tree for multiple families. So, I want to start with one account and traverse each record, then for matching SSN records and flag each one with family id.

Comment: I did something similar some years ago using a Stored Procedure: Insert/Select all rows into a temp table with a new column set to the original `AccountNo`.  `min(newCol) over (partition by SSN)` will find the lowest number for rows with the same SSN, use this to Update newCol and do the same for Name & Address, etc. Then you must repeat this in a loop until there's no row updated.

Comment: Thank you. Something similar I am doing. But for looping what will be good way? I have added additional example in original post to give idea of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `MIN OVER` matches multiple rows with the same value, use this to assign this result to the existing data and repeat the process until no more rows are updated:

```
-- untested (modified existing Teradata SQL to SQL Server syntax)
DECLARE @activity_count INTEGER

select *, 
   row_number() over (order by AccountNo) as rn, -- you need a key for the UPDATEs
   row_number() over (order by AccountNo) as GroupNo -- matched rows get the same group
into #temp
from tab

set @activity_count = @@ROWCOUNT

while @activity_count > 0 -- recursive part, repeat until no more row UPDATEd
begin

   update #temp 
   set GroupNo = x.newGrp
   from 
     (select rn, SSN, 
         min(GroupNo) over (partition by SSN) as newGrp -- same SSN
      from #temp
     ) as x
   where #temp.rn = x.rn
     and #temp.GroupNo <> x.newGrp -- only new group members

   set @activity_count = @@ROWCOUNT

   update #temp 
   set GroupNo = x.newGrp
   from 
     (select rn, AccountNo, 
         min(GroupNo) over (partition by AccountNo) as newGrp -- same AccountNo
      from #temp
     ) as x
   where #temp.rn = x.rn
     and #temp.GroupNo <> x.newGrp -- only new group members

   set @activity_count = @activity_count + @@ROWCOUNT

   -- repeat previous UPDATE/SET for any other column to match

end -- while

select dense_rank() over (order by GroupNo) as expectedResult, *
from #temp
order by GroupNo, rn
```

To be able to include your address-matching logic your function must reduce a single address to a simplified form.

Comment: Thank you. This gives really good performance. I am able to process 10m records within an hour. Only problem I am trying to figure out is address comparison, because I can not group it. I have function which compares two addresses after some manipulation and then generates score which should be above certain threshold then record matches.

Answer (score 0):

Going over every row and comparing it to every other row with a cursor is going to be very slow.  For finding duplicates easier I would group them and only return ones with > 1 in the group.  Here is a sample:

```
SELECT AccountNumber, count(1)
FROM foo
GROUP BY AccountNumber
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Once you have found the duplicates you can start merging/deleting them.